# Detached entity passed to persist, but the entity was just persisted

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm getting this error that I shouldn't be getting. First, I persist an appointment1, with doctor1, and it gets saved. Then, on appointment4, I get detached entity error, but doctor1 is already saved = it has an ID set, it's in the database. What's going on? What's the resolution?
Thank you.

```
Appointment appointment1 = new Appointment("08/11/11", patient1,
        payment1, doctor1);
Appointment appointment2 = new Appointment("12-11-2008", patient2,
        payment2, doctor2);
Appointment appointment3 = new Appointment("13-11-2008", patient3,
        payment3, doctor2);
Appointment appointment4 = new Appointment("14-11-2008", patient1,
        payment4, doctor1);

appointmentRepository.save(appointment1);
// detached entity passed to persist: domain.Doctor
appointmentRepository.save(appointment4);
```

Comment: What's with the minus????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently it's enough to just add `@Transaction` for the method containing the code. By default, transactions are limited to a single repository method, so when it returns, the appointment, and it's children, become detached. Adding `@Transaction` keeps them all in the same transaction.